# How do I use dce:explode() in typo3?

Tags: typo3, typo3-extensions

sorry, but I don't know which other Tags to use for this question.

I'm using typo3 with dce extension. I want to use dce:explode to separate values from a comma separated string:

```
{field.category -> dce:explode(delimiter:',')}
```

field.category contains "value1,value2,value3"

But this gives always an error in the frontend:
Oops, an error occurred! Code: 2015082814003052e1ee30

Can anyone help?

Comment: Either disable the [`contentObjectExceptionHandler`](https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/TyposcriptReference/Setup/Config/Index.html#setup-config-contentobjectexceptionhandler) or use the development-preset (available in the install tool) to get better error messages and the cause of this.

Comment: Thanks Jost. I'll try this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it. I'm just a typo3 noob and simply forgot to define the dce namespace before using it:

```
{namespace dce=ArminVieweg\Dce\ViewHelpers}
```

Now it works fine